# Dataframe output difference compared to what's supposed to be in the textbook

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe,names, containing columns of name, sex births, year etc for "Python for Data Analysis" book.

When I type `names`, it gives me below.

```
    name sex  births  year      prop
0        Mary   F    7065  1880  0.077643
1        Anna   F    2604  1880  0.028618
2        Emma   F    2003  1880  0.022013
3   Elizabeth   F    1939  1880  0.021309
4      Minnie   F    1746  1880  0.019188
5    Margaret   F    1578  1880  0.017342
6         Ida   F    1472  1880  0.016177
7       Alice   F    1414  1880  0.015540
8      Bertha   F    1320  1880  0.014507...
```

However, in the book, it's supposed to be like below:

```
In [378]: names
Out[378]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Int64Index: 1690784 entries, 0 to 1690783 Data columns:
name 1690784 non-null values
sex 1690784 non-null values births 1690784 non-null values
year 1690784 non-null values
prop 1690784 non-null values dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(2)
```

Would someone know any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That's what modern `pandas` should be expected to show, so I don't think there's anything needing to be fixed.  If you want something more like that representation, you can call [`df.info()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html).  Note that the below is only taken from the values you showed, so it's obviously much smaller:

```
In [20]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 5 columns):
name      9 non-null object
sex       9 non-null object
births    9 non-null int64
year      9 non-null int64
prop      9 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 324.0+ bytes
```

I vaguely remember that when frames were large enough in the past the default might have been to give an `info`-like overview but I can't remember the details.  In any case, I don't think anything's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand better now :)